# Command in ViewModel

Tags: xamarin.forms

i was trying to find a solution on the internet but what i found didn't really answer my question as i am beginner so it seems quite advanced for me.

I have a page with like 10 buttons each of them performing different action I am using Command. However i now have this in my constructor and since i have 5 more buttons then i would have five more commands in my constructor and i am getting a feeling that this not right.. is there any way i can do this eithout this crazy stuff in my constructor?

```
 public DictionaryViewModel()
            : base(listenCultureChanges: true)
        {
            Task.Run(async () => await LoadAllDataForDictionary()).Wait();
            PlayPauseCommand = new Command(() => StartOrStopPlaying());
            HideLabelsCommand = new Command(() => HideLabels());
            MakeWebViewLargeEnCommand = new Command(() => MakeWebViewLargeEN());
            MakeWebViewLargeCzCommand = new Command(() => MakeWebViewLargeCZ());
            RemoveWordFromUserDictionaryCommand = new Command(() => RemoveWordFromUserDictionary());
        }
```

Comment: How about you put this in a method and call that method?

Comment: It is possible to use one command for all the buttons. But you have to play with the command parameter to know the exact action to execute in your viewmodel. Each command parameter will have unique value that you can get in the viewmodel and then perform the corresponding action

Comment: @MarcelCallo ok, so i guess this is  a bit advanced level. I will try, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is Ok, If you put 10 Commands in your constructor.

But If you load data from SQLite into a ViewModel, You should  `bindingContext` in `OnAppearing`. For example, you used `Task.Run(async () => await LoadAllDataForDictionary()).Wait();` in your constructor, You should create a method in your ViewModel like following code.

```
 public void PopulateCollection()
        {
            Task.Run(async () => await LoadAllDataForDictionary()).Wait();
        }
```

Then load the data in `OnAppearing` method in your page background code.

```
           protected override async void OnAppearing()
            {
                base.OnAppearing();

                var pageVm = this.BindingContext as MyPageVm;

                if (pageVm != null)
                {
                    pageVm.PopulateCollection();
                }
            }
```

Comment: There is a huge flaw in this, for instance, every time the user comes back to this page the SQLite DB will be called again to re-fetch the data that already exists, or if the user goes in the background and comes back for instance